# Как убрать вложенность операторов using?

Tags: c#

При посылке HTTP-запроса используется нижеследующий код (код взят из MSDN, и обернут операторами using). Как избежать многократной вложенности операторов?

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В using можно указывать несколько утверждений через запятую. Но при этом требуется, чтобы они были одного типа. получится что-то вроде:

```
using (IDisposable response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(),
       IDisposable stream = response.GetResponseStream(), 
       IDisposable reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        { 
            result = (StreamReader)reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Кстати, раз уж используется using, то close вызывать необязательно.

Comment: > Кстати, раз уж используется using, то close вызывать необязательно.

а есть гарантия, что в деструкторе поток сам закроется?

Comment: Гарантия есть.

Если вам интересно, попробуйте сами:

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("d:\workdir\file.txt"))
    {
         // Некоторые действия с файлом file.txt которые невероятно сложны и запутаны...
    }


    File.Delete("d:\workdir\file.txt");


Незакрытый поток в последней строчке вызывает исключение :-)

Comment: работать будет, но жизнь научила в таких вещах быть излишне дотошным.

то что работает сегодня, может не работать завтра (не раз такое было с продуктами того же microsoft. и если документированные возможности они ещё как-то поддерживают, то остальное может меняться.

кроме того, судя по этому описанию, если не вызвать close, могут не сохраниться изменения:

> При очистке потока основной кодировщик не очищается до тех пор, пока реализация Flush или Close не будет вызвана явно.

в общем я стараюсь не экономить на таких вещах, привычка принудительно всё закрывать по finally никогда не подводила

Comment: [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx)

> The object provided to the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources.

И далее:

[Stream.Dispose Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227422.aspx)

> This method disposes the stream, *by writing any changes* to the backing store and closing the stream to release resources. 

Так что да, можно доверять.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже было сказано, в случае объектов одного типа можно просто перечислить их через запятую.

```
using (A a1 = new A(), a2 = new A())
{
    //code
}
```

В случае же объектов разных типов максимально допустимое сокращение -- это опускание фигурных скобок.

```
using (A a = new A())
using (B b = new B())
{
    //code
}
```

А ещё преимущество такого использования `using` как раз и заключается в невозможности забыть про освобождение ресурсов, так как оно произойдёт автоматически при выходе из области. Так что ваши `Close()` здесь излишни.

Comment: я бы всё-таки использовал метод close, раз уж его завели и раз уж сами Microsoft его используют.

такое небрежное отношение к коду - причина довольно многих ошибок, имхо.

Comment: Выдержка описания метода `Close()` из MSDN: "Этот метод вызывает Dispose". В результате получаем двойное освобождение. В Microsoft, конечно, не поленились написать защиту от повторных вызовов, но я бы этим не злоупотреблял.

Comment: вот именно, что Close вызывает Dispose, а кроме этого он ещё много чего может делать.

Если бы наоборот, Dispose вызывал Close - вопросов бы вообще не было.

Кстати забавно, код с msdn:

                isoFile.Dispose();
                isoFile.Close();

Answer (score 1):

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        stream.Close();
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

я так понимаю это эквивалентно такому коду:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
            stream.Close();
        }
        response.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
       if (response != null)
          ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
    }
}
```

всё, что внутри try блока можно унести в отдельную ф-цию.